# regular expression and Ant

Tags: regex, ant

Has anyone worked with ant properties and regular expressions before? If so would you know how this string should be corrected to get it working?

```
<replaceregexp 
file="../cms-distribution/src/main/properties/editorial/common/csdtflags.properties" 
flags="s" 
match="${typeSplitFirstPart}:([a-zA-Z,0-9-]+)([;])?"
replace="${typeSplitFirstPart}:\1,${uid}\2"
byline="true"/>



Error : java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0

${typeSplitFirstPart}:([a-zA-Z,0-9-]+)([;])?
```

TypeSplitFirstPart is an ant property so it needs to be referenced this way - ${typeSplitFirstPart} to get the value. Need to escape special characters such as $,{,} with a backslash, but then it does not get the value of the property. escaping the $ only retrieves the value of typeSplitFirstPart however it throws this error -

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1

\Template:([a-zA-Z,0-9-]+)([;])?
```

Note - here `${typeSplitFirstPart}` has been read properly and its value "Template" is written.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the last dash in the list needs to be escaped:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)
```

Comment: - java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near   index 0
    ${typeSplitFirstPart}:([a-zA-Z,0-9\-]+)([;])?

Comment: The comma also need to be escaped.

Comment: need to look for comma too...cant escape

Comment: Comma is only used for determine occurences interval, like `[a-z]{1,5}`. If you want to match the character `,` too, the correct regex is `([a-zA-Z\,0-9\-]+)`